# Are there any books on Seder Hishtalshelus?

Tags: product-recommendation, jewish-books, mysticism-kabbalah

I was wondering whether I could find a book which describes the stages of the seder hishtalshelus.

The Seder Hishtalshelus refers to the chain-like descent of spiritual worlds (Olam/Olamot) between God and Creation. It is part of Kabbalah.

Comment: There's a book by that name - http://seforimsets.com/index.php?route=product/product&product_id=1439

Comment: Thank you, unfortunately there's no description in English, but I'll make a note of it.

Comment: I have a book, not found in Hebrewbooks,  called "מפתחי חכמת הקבלה" written by  a bochur killed in shoa,  a short book,  with great haskamot,  which precisely addresses the hishtalshelut haolamot

Comment: @kouty sounds like a great answer. Want to post it as such?

Comment: @msh210 I don't posted it as answer because it is even nt a link, and further I soon that bianca freire looks for english texts. Thank you. But this book, and the history of the author to is very moving.

Comment: @msh210 see this http://www.haaretz.co.il/misc/1.1004236

Comment: the book is here https://books.google.co.il/books/about/ספר_מפתחי_חכמת_האמת.html?id=xSUsAQAAMAAJ&redir_esc=y    mafteche chochmat haemet

Comment: https://books.google.com/books?id=CNCQ_MCwEDAC&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&printsec=frontcover&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false

Answer (score 3):

There's a letter from the sixth Lubavitcher Rebbe concerning the four world's (Atzilut, Beriah, Yitzira, and Asiyah) that described this process in detail. It has been translated as part of the Chassidic Heritage Series with copious footnotes and can be found here :http://store.kehotonline.com/mobile/prodinfo.asp?number=efr-four

I'm sure it's also available on Amazon.com

Answer (score 2):

You could try Section 2, chapter 1, "How Providence Works" from [Derekh Hashem, (The Way of God) by the Ramchal](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Derech-Hashem-Torah-Classics-Library/dp/087306769X).

Answer (score 1):

I recommend the Ramchal's 138 Openings of Wisdom and it's available online:

https://www.azamra.org/spirit/openings.php

Comment: This is what I read, but it's pretty hardcore: https://godssecret.files.wordpress.com/2010/06/only-parzufim2.pdf

Answer (score 0):

A basic understanding of "the chaining down"/histalshelut can be found in Rabbi Aryeh Kaplan's book called "Inner Space." Also neirot.com has Hebrew/English books. One in particular is "The Gate of Unity." The Rabbi M Miller's explanation ofTanya is also a great place to start "The Book of Inbetweeners." Happy adventures!